# Suspending laptop fails ~50% of the time

Tags: arch-linux, power-management, suspend, acpi, thinkpad

Running ArchLinux and GNOME 3 on a Thinkpad X220.

When I suspend my laptop it goes into sleep mode and the LED ring around the power button fades in and out.

When a suspend fails, the LED ring and the screen is on but I can't do anything. My only recovery is to do a hard reset.

This only happens 33 - 50% of the time within the last few months, but it never happened a year ago.

How can I debug / fix this issue?

Output from `sudo journalctl --since=today | tac | sed -n '/-- Reboot --/{n;:r;/-- Reboot --/q;p;n;b r}' | tac`:

```
Mar 17 15:10:49 noa systemd-logind[349]: Suspend key pressed.
Mar 17 15:10:49 noa NetworkManager[332]: <info> sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Mar 17 15:10:49 noa NetworkManager[332]: <info> sleeping or disabling...
Mar 17 15:10:49 noa NetworkManager[332]: <info> (eth0): device state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [20 10 37]
Mar 17 15:10:49 noa NetworkManager[332]: <info> (eth0): cleaning up...
Mar 17 15:10:49 noa NetworkManager[332]: <info> (eth0): taking down device.
Mar 17 15:10:50 noa NetworkManager[332]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [30 10 37]
Mar 17 15:10:50 noa NetworkManager[332]: <info> (wlan0): cleaning up...
Mar 17 15:10:50 noa NetworkManager[332]: <info> (wlan0): taking down device.
Mar 17 15:10:50 noa systemd[1]: Starting Sleep.
Mar 17 15:10:50 noa systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Mar 17 15:10:50 noa systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Mar 17 15:10:50 noa dbus-daemon[353]: dbus[353]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=349 comm="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.57" (uid=1000 pid=638 comm="gnome-session --session=xmonad ")
Mar 17 15:10:50 noa dbus[353]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=349 comm="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.57" (uid=1000 pid=638 comm="gnome-session --session=xmonad ")
```

Comment: If you can't `ssh` in to read the logs, you can use the [hack on the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Journal) to read logs from a previous boot...

Comment: What machine is this? All up to date? Some BIOS issue maybe?

Comment: I can't `ssh` in, I've updated the details in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, [Netconsole](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netconsole) can be tried as a debuging tool and [Tuxonice](http://tuxonice.net/) as an alternative which (hopefully) can overcome the issue with hardware you use.